# Creating animated timeline in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, animation, timeslider

I can't find any options in ArcGIS timeslider to create a timeline like presented in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkf86Ft1muA&t=12m57s). The video itself is a guide for creating time animation, but no information is given how to create such timeline like in the end.

I have tried to search some information about that and can't find anything usefull.

Does ArcGIS support such functionality?

I need an auto-refreshed timeline (which is presented not as usual date text).
It should be animated line where each date is a vertical line on a timeline.
Also I need to label each date on it as a text. See picture below (frame by frame animation).

[image]

Added a post at [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000005FdrIAE), to add such functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArcGIS does not have functionality beyond what you already mentioned; the [time slider](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005z0000000z000000). The time slider offers no options on customization, such as appearance. I have created graphics like the one shown in the video. In order to accomplish these graphics I made use of Adobe Flash. Map data can be exported from ArcGIS into Adobe Flash by executing File -> Export Map and then selecting AI (*.ai) as your file type.